# Networking for CentOS 6.6 on VirtualBox

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos

I have created 2 guests with 2 Network interfaces each - all 4 of which have the *"Attached To:"* set to "**Internal Network"**. The aim is to create a simple internal network with no access to the Host (for now).

**VM1**

*ifcfg-eth1*

```
DEVICE=eth1
HWADDR=<Unique MacAddr Here>
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=10.0.0.101
NETMASK=255.0.0.0
```

*ifcfg-eth2*

```
DEVICE=eth2
HWADDR=<Unique MacAddr Here>
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=10.0.0.102
NETMASK=255.0.0.0
```

**VM2**

*ifcfg-eth1*

```
DEVICE=eth1
HWADDR=<Unique MacAddr Here>
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=10.0.0.103
NETMASK=255.0.0.0
```

*ifcfg-eth2*

```
DEVICE=eth2
HWADDR=<Unique MacAddr Here>
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=10.0.0.104
NETMASK=255.0.0.0
```

After this was set up, the network interfaces were started using the ifup command (for good measure the VMs were rebooted too)

The `resolv.conf` for both VMs are empty by default and was left as is.

The /etc/hosts file for both the VMs reads like so:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain
::1       localhost localhost.localdomain
```

The `route -n` command for both the VMs are as follows:
[image: Command Output]

The main issue is the VMs at the moment, cannot ping each other and shows the following error - **"Destination Host Unreachable"**

Any help in pointing out the errors would be appreciated. On a separate note, would it be possible to ping between the 2 Network interfaces on the same VM (at the moment, it shows the same error as above).

Comment: What is the output of `ifconfig -a`?

Comment: @Lambert - added the output for `ifconfig`:
VM1: http://imgur.com/Hmhw04i,hvTyJ1i#1
VM2: http://imgur.com/Hmhw04i,hvTyJ1i#0

Comment: You should be able to ping from eth1 to eth2 and vice versa. Did you use the same 'intnet' value for all the interfaces?

Comment: @Lambert - that was it. I'd named them intnet1,2,3..etc. Changing them all to the same name fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To actually answer this question based on the comments:

The network name (default: intnet) needs to be the same when the hosts/interfaces share the same network.